# Gradle: Build multiple applications that use the same components (multi-multi-project build)

Tags: gradle

I have different components (let's say comp1..compN), some of them depend on
others. I'd like to build different applications (app1..appN), that use these
components. What's a good way to set up gradle projects for this scenario?

Currently I have a flat structure like:

```
dir
  app1
  app2
  appN
  comp1
  comp2
  comp3
  compN
```

Let's say app1 uses comp1 and 2. I added "includeFlat" for comp1 and 2 to settings.gradle of app1. Since comp2
depends on comp1, I added this dependency to build.gradle of comp2.

Now I'm
able to build app1. Unfortunately I can't build comp2 from
the directory comp2, since it cannot resolve the dependency on comp1 (but I can
build it from directory app1 with `gradle :comp2:build`).

(Should I use a multi-project build for comp2: add includeFlat for comp1 to
settings.gradle of comp2? I'm not sure it this is the way to go.)

Is there a better way to set this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a regular multi-project build. Just create a single `settings.gradle` file in your root directory and include (not `includeFlat`) each project regardless whether it's an app project or a components project. Then define dependencies between the projects in the respective `build.gradle` files.

It should not matter from what directory you call `gradle` in the command line. Simply use task paths if you just want to build a single project (e.g. `gradle :app1:build`). Once you start using the Gradle wrapper (`gradlew`), which is recommended, you gonna need to call it from the root directory anyhow.